# Code FQL analogue Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like to get in FQL, the analogue of this code Graph API explorer that gives me checkins and places where you've been tagged:

me?fields=id,name,checkins.fields(place,id),locations.fields(place,id)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't tried anything yet. Please make sure to put some efforts by yourself before asking any question on Stack Overflow and do share your experience while asking any question.

Have a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

I can still guide you regarding the solution to your problem. Please refer to the following documentations:

- [FQL Overview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql)
- [FQL checkin Table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/checkin/)
- [FQL post_location Table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/location_post/)

You can always try and test your queries using the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/).

Comment: I'm Italian and I hope to be able to express myself well. It is not true that I have not tried to do anything, so it's a long time that I'm working to solve this problem, having also written on the forum questions and pieces of code that I used and for which I wanted to help. I was hoping just to get some help or clue to do my job without feeling give bad reviews from anyone.

Comment: Hey! Don't take it in the wrong way. I said so because your question didn't include any code or query that you've already tried. Also, I thought you are new to Stack Overflow, so knowing how to ask a good question might help you in future. I even tried to help you by providing some links to the documentation.

Comment: The work I am doing is part of my thesis in computer science, and I want to do a good job and to learn how to use well the android sdk and facebook. Now I am at the beginning and unfortunately I still have some problems.
Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Wish you good luck with your thesis. Remember, every problem has a solution. So, keep up the good work. Stack Overflow is there to help you. :)

Comment: Thanks Rahil Arora :)

Comment: Rahil Hello,I hope to not be rude and do not disturb,I wanted to ask you a question. I have read the documents in the links you gave me, and when I was able to write this in the graph API:524983333?fields=checkins.fields(place)                         which has as similar in this FQL query:                             SELECT author_uid,coords FROM checkin WHERE author_uid=524983333                                                I noticed, however, that not all my friends return the same results. It 'a normal thing? That is not with all the friends you will get exactly the same results?thanks

Comment: I don't know whether it's normal or not. But sometimes the results you get from Graph API can be different the ones you get from FQL. It just how the Facebook API behaves. The results also depend on the privacy settings of your friends and can be different. Facebook API is not perfect and is still under development. You might have also come across on Stack Overflow related some strange behavior of Facebook Graph API.

Comment: Did you see that I am working? Now I just have to play the part of location_post and put it together to checkin to get all the results of facebook places